# Create an array and try to declare inside loop found error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

```
package sortpractice;

public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {

int id;
String name;
int age;
long salary;

public Employee(int id, String name, int age, long salary) {

    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.salary = salary;

}

public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return this.age;
}

public long getSalary() {
    return this.salary;
}

public String toString() {
    return "[id=" + this.id + ", name=" + this.name + ", age=" + this.age + ", salary="
            + this.salary + "]";
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Employee emp) {

    return (this.id - emp.id);
}
```

}

---

```
package sortpractice;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class JavaObjectSorting {

int[] id = {3, 1, 2};
String[] name = {"A", "B", "C"};
int[] age = {10, 20, 30};
long[] salary = {100, 200, 300};

public JavaObjectSorting() {

    for (int i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
        Employee[] test = new Employee[i];
        System.out.println(i);
        test[i] = new Employee(id[i], name[i], age[i], salary[i]);

    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    JavaObjectSorting j = new JavaObjectSorting();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put following line outside the for loop

```
   Employee[] test = new Employee[id.length];
```

Now you code will like this:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
    test[i] = new Employee(id[i], name[i], age[i], salary[i]);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

for i = 0 .. it will be

```
    Employee[] test = new Employee[0];
```

so declare and initiate the array before the loop

```
    Employee[] test = new Employee[id.lenght];
for (int i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
    test[i] = new Employee(id[i], name[i], age[i], salary[i]);

}
```